# Java: How to read csv files of different data types and lengths into an ArrayList< Object>?

Tags: java, csv, arraylist

I have created a parent class Object with 3 parameters, a child class ObjectA with 4 parameters and a child class ObjectB with 8 parameters. These parameters have different data types. I need to read a csv file A (with 4 columns) and a csv file B (with 8 columns) into one ArrayList< Object>. Is this possible?

Comment: Maybe this would help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40074903/10743176 ? Just that you need one ArrayList and two loops, one for each of your csv-file/Subclass.

Comment: When you say "parent class Object with 3 parameters", do you mean the constructor has 3 parameters?

Comment: @Scratte yes the Object constructor has 3 parameters, ObjectA 4 and ObjectB 8 (noting user1855085 's comment below that it can't be called Object - so I will change it to something else)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible, except that the parent class cannot be called 'Object'.

```
    ArrayList<ObjectParent> list = new ArrayList<ObjectParent>();
    list.add(new ObjectA(aPath));
    list.add(new ObjectB(bPath));
```

Comment: I tried but it wasn't happy because the number of parameters for ObjectParent, ObjectA and ObjectB are different :(